# Is there an appropriate "potting" compound for a DC power barrel connector?

Tags: connector, potting, adhesives

I need to modify the DC connector on about 100 AC/DC power supplies and will be installing a barrel connector like this:
[image]

I would like to make the connector more permanent and prevent a user from opening the connector as well as increase the physical bond between the wire and the connector. I'm thinking I would like to squirt a blob of some compound (potting compound?) before threading the connector back together to lock it all up.

Is there an appropriate compound for this application?

Comment: What quantities will you be building?

Comment: Around 100 will be made. Edited question accordingly.

Comment: Usually a 'molded' connector does not have the outer shell, but the compound is injected into a mold.   Some outfits will sell the cord and molded plug as an assembly.

Answer (score 2):

For casual use, from the Amateur Radio Relay League Hints & Kinks, just using a good grade of hot glue should do well, and can still be removed. For permanent use try 2-part epoxy like JB Weld, it can even be machined after drying.

Comment: How do you propose to inject the hot glue into the connector? If over an opened yet connector, then the glue will cool off fast, and you won't be able to screw to plastic body in.

Comment: With 100V, be careful with the properties of the hot melt.

Comment: @JasonHan I don't think anyone uses barrel connectors for 100V, for reasons that should be obvious. When my son was a toddler he would sometime sit quietly beside me as I worked on the computer. One time he began to cry, stopped then again. Turned out he had put a barrel connector energized with 24V in his mouth- I tried it myself- for science- quite a jolt. Two times was enough to learn.